# Showing a +255 byte in a byte[]

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I really hope someone can help me.

I have a single `byte[]` that has to show the amount of bytes in die `byte[]` to follow. Now my value is above 255. Is there a way to display/enter a large number?

Comment: What do you mean by "a single byte[]" exactly? Do you mean you've got a byte array of length 1? Your question is very unclear. Code would help...

Comment: it almost sounds like you are expecting to store a value larger than 255 in a byte...that doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: You cannot store a value greater than 255 in a byte, so there would be no way to display a byte value above that.

Comment: Do you mean you're using the first entry in the array to store the number of entries total in that array?

Comment: I got a byte array of 300. This is going into a message sent to a server. Now one of my bytes has to show the length of the byte[] so that the server knows when to stop reading. Now that byte has to have the value of 299.

Comment: This is for a current server, and I am working from their API document.

Comment: Does the server know how to deal with lengths greater than 255? That is, if you sent an int instead of the byte, would it handle this properly?

Comment: If you need to store something larger than 255 in a single byte, you can't. If you has a number of bytes available, you simply take the integer value and extract the discrete bytes from that. See my answer.

Comment: driis... that makes sense, but how do one do that?

Comment: I see a handful of options: (1) use multiple bytes to represent the length, (2) use a larger data type to represent the length, (3) restrict the length of the byte array to 255 per message, or (4) change your design. Without more information, I can't give a solid recommendation.

Comment: You could also break the array into two or more separate ones (each with length less than 255) and send them one after the other to the server, treating each like a separate transaction.

Comment: No, 299 cannot be represented by a `byte`. If you can't change the format of the message, then you have to restrict the length of each message to 255 bytes. You can either display an error or break larger messages into several smaller ones.

Answer (score 3):

A byte holds a value from 0 to 255. To represent 299, you either have to use 2 bytes, or use a scheme (which the receiver will have to use as well) where the value in the byte is interpreted as more than its nominal value in order to expand the possible range of values. For instance, the value could be the length / 2. This would allow lengths of 0 - 510, but would allow only even lengths (odd length arrays would need a pad byte).

Comment: I blame fumbly fingers and a bad track-pad. Sorry! Corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can use two (or more) bytes to represent a number larger than 255. Is that what you want ?

```
short value = 2451;
byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
```

If this is needed in order to exchange data with some external system, remember to read about [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Driis! That makes my head work in the right direction! That works perfectly in my situation. I overlooked that i had two bytes to display the value! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you consider a good approach. You can perform some form of encoding to allow you store larger than 2 bytes worth of data. I.e. perhaps setting the first byte as 0xFF means you will consider the next byte as part of its data. 
`[0x01,0x0A,0xFF,0x0A]`
Would be interpreted as 3 values of `[1,10,265]`